# Programación funcional JS

Tags: javascript

Cordial saludo compañer@s, vengo siguiendo un curso de JS en freeCodeCamp, y estoy en un ejemplo que no me queda claro, el cual es este:

```js
let fixedValue = 4;

    function incrementer() {
      return fixedValue+1;    
    }
    console.log(fixedValue + "   "+ incrementer())//4 5 respectivamente
```

Pero si le coloco  **return fixedValue++;**    me arroja 4 4 respectivamente, lo cual me resulta confuso, ya que con ++ o +1 era igual, alguien que me pueda explicar que sucede tras bambalinas?

Comment: Como puedes ver aquí mismo, ejecutando tu código retorna `4 5`.

Comment: Explico, es un ejercicio donde proponen retornar la variable global fixedValue incrementada en 1, lo cual se  logra con fixedValue+1, pero si coloco fixedValue++ esta no logra con el cometido de incrementarse, allí es donde radica mi duda del por que pasa esto. No se si me hago entender

Comment: @GuerreroAntonio, te aconsejo leer [Operadores aritméticos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operadores_aritm%C3%A9ticos). El funcionamiento de `x++` no es igual al de `x+1`

Comment: ummm, ya entiendo por donde va el asunto según mencionas lo de operadores aritmeticos, ya que con ++ primero retorna y luego incrementa, pense que era otro el motivo, gracias bro.

Comment: Pregunto como dar como solucionada la pregunta? Gracias

Comment: Tienes estas opciones para solucionar la pregunta: 1) Escribes tu mismo la respuesta y al cabo de 48 horas la puedes aceptar para que la comunidad lo sepa, 2) Esperas a que alguien intente responderla y si está bien la aceptas o 3) Borras la pregunta y tan amigos

Answer (score 2):

En tu pregunta, te cuestionas el porque en esta función **no** se devuelve el número representado por la variable **fixedValue** incrementado en uno cuando lo escribes usando el *operador unario de incremento* **`++`** así:

```js
let fixedValue = 4;

function incrementer() {
  return fixedValue++
}
console.log(fixedValue + "   " + incrementer()) //4 4 respectivamente
```

Cuyo resultado muestra el mismo número pasado, 4.

La respuesta, comentada por @Marcos, aparece en [la documentación del operador unario de incremento](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#operadores_aritm%C3%A9ticos):

> si se usa como operador sufijo (x++), devuelve el valor de su operando
> antes de agregar uno.

Es decir, al hacer un **return** directamente sobre la variable a incrementar, **nos va a devolver el valor actual** de la variable **antes** de incrementarla en uno.

### Métodos para incrementar en 1 la variable y solucionar este comportamiento

---

1. Usando el operador unario de incremento **`++`** como **sufijo** pero **devolverlo después**. Es decir:

---

```js
let fixedValue = 4;

function incrementer() {
  fixedValue++
  return fixedValue
}
console.log(fixedValue + "   " + incrementer()) //4 5 respectivamente
```

donde primero incrementamos la variable para **después** hacer su **return**.

---

2. Usando el operador unario de incremento **`++`** como **prefijo** y **devolverlo immediatamente**

---

```js
let fixedValue = 4;

function incrementer() {
  return ++fixedValue
}
console.log(fixedValue + "   " + incrementer()) //4 5 respectivamente
```

porque tal como dice su documentación:

> Si se usa como operador prefijo (++x), devuelve el valor de su
> operando después de agregar uno;

Es decir, en este caso, **sí** podemos hacer el **return** directamente porque el valor del operando ya ha sido incrementado al usar el operador **`++`** como **prefijo**.

---

3. Simplemente le sumamos 1 a la variable en el propio **return** dentro de la función:

---

```js
let fixedValue = 4;

function incrementer() {
  return fixedValue + 1;
}
console.log(fixedValue + "   " + incrementer()) //4 5 respectivamente
```